# Migrate to new SSL Certificate in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl

I currently have a site residing at https://beta.myapp.mydomain.com.

We would like to change this to https://myapp2.mydomain.com and have acquired the SSL certificate to do this.   We'd like to do this in a manner that is transparent to our current users.

However, IIS won't let me add a second SSL binding to port 443, and I don't see a way to add another cert to the existing binding.

Is there an approach that will let me accomplish this without a wildcard cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind 2 SSL certs to the same website, you have to set up the myapp2 site as a second site and bind your SSL cert to it. And so it depends on your definition of "transparent". You can add a redirect from the beta site to the myapp2 site, that would be pretty transparent I would think.

Comment: I can create the two sites, but is it possible to set up two SSL certs on port 443 on the same machine?

Comment: Yes this is possible. You either bind the sites to different IP addresses, or if that's not an option you have to use https host headers. On IIS 8 you can type in the host header using the bindings window in the GUI. For IIS 7 and earlier you have to use the command line to add an https host header. Here's a link: https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-7.htm#CommandLine